# Javascript: Not able to store the string in variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to a read the string "----\n@-v-\n----\n--^-" in the input variable.

```
console.log("Program Started");
var input = "-->v\n@-^-\n---^"; //not ending with
console.log("reading");

var output = getDistance(input);

if(output === -999){
console.log("Invalid input string");
}
else if(output === -1){
console.log("Infinite loop");
}
else{
console.log("Distance covers by beam: "+output+" blocks");
}
console.log(output);
```

I am runnin it through Eclipse plugin for node.js. I can see "Program Started" in console but can't see "reading". Program stops there and nothing happens further. can some one please tell me whats the issue here?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/6e5Xa/

Comment: That’s weird. How are you running it?

Comment: Lies... this can't be the real code.

Comment: Hi I have updated the code.. I have copied it as it is.. I am running it in Eclipse. I'm using node.js plugin for Eclipse

Comment: No I'm not collecting it. But when I change the last '^' character to something else. then it can go to next line. I can get required output. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: What is the definition of getDistance?  problem might lie there...